# AWS Lambda handler for Spring Boot is not passing ServletContext

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, aws-lambda

When triggering my Spring Boot application on an AWS Lambda, I keep getting the error `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: ServletContext must not be null`. I am unsure why this is happening and would like some more information.

Here is the stack trace:

```java
2020-03-25 19:52:09.444 ERROR 8 --- [           main] c.a.s.p.internal.LambdaContainerHandler  : Error while handling request
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: ServletContext must not be null
at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:198) ~[spring-core-5.1.14.RELEASE.jar:5.1.14.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.context.support.WebApplicationContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(WebApplicationContextUtils.java:112) ~[spring-web-5.1.14.RELEASE.jar:5.1.14.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.context.support.WebApplicationContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(WebApplicationContextUtils.java:101) ~[spring-web-5.1.14.RELEASE.jar:5.1.14.RELEASE]
at com.lukeshay.restapi.security.JwtAuthorizationFilter.doFilterInternal(JwtAuthorizationFilter.java:49) ~[task/:na]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.1.14.RELEASE.jar:5.1.14.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:200) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:97) ~[spring-web-5.1.14.RELEASE.jar:5.1.14.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.1.14.RELEASE.jar:5.1.14.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:74) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.1.14.RELEASE.jar:5.1.14.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.1.14.RELEASE.jar:5.1.14.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358) ~[spring-web-5.1.14.RELEASE.jar:5.1.14.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271) ~[spring-web-5.1.14.RELEASE.jar:5.1.14.RELEASE]
at com.amazonaws.serverless.proxy.internal.servlet.FilterChainHolder.doFilter(FilterChainHolder.java:90) ~[aws-serverless-java-container-core-1.4.jar:na]
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.1.14.RELEASE.jar:5.1.14.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.1.14.RELEASE.jar:5.1.14.RELEASE]
at com.amazonaws.serverless.proxy.internal.servlet.FilterChainHolder.doFilter(FilterChainHolder.java:90) ~[aws-serverless-java-container-core-1.4.jar:na]
at com.lukeshay.restapi.config.CORSConfiguration.doFilter(CORSConfiguration.java:43) ~[task/:na]
at com.amazonaws.serverless.proxy.internal.servlet.FilterChainHolder.doFilter(FilterChainHolder.java:90) ~[aws-serverless-java-container-core-1.4.jar:na]
at com.amazonaws.serverless.proxy.internal.servlet.AwsLambdaServletContainerHandler.doFilter(AwsLambdaServletContainerHandler.java:150) ~[aws-serverless-java-container-core-1.4.jar:na]
at com.amazonaws.serverless.proxy.spring.SpringBootLambdaContainerHandler.handleRequest(SpringBootLambdaContainerHandler.java:143) ~[aws-serverless-java-container-springboot2-1.4.jar:na]
at com.amazonaws.serverless.proxy.spring.SpringBootLambdaContainerHandler.handleRequest(SpringBootLambdaContainerHandler.java:43) ~[aws-serverless-java-container-springboot2-1.4.jar:na]
at com.amazonaws.serverless.proxy.internal.LambdaContainerHandler.proxy(LambdaContainerHandler.java:211) ~[aws-serverless-java-container-core-1.4.jar:na]
at com.amazonaws.serverless.proxy.internal.LambdaContainerHandler.proxyStream(LambdaContainerHandler.java:246) ~[aws-serverless-java-container-core-1.4.jar:na]
at com.lukeshay.restapi.StreamLambdaHandler.handleRequest(StreamLambdaHandler.java:56) ~[task/:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at lambdainternal.EventHandlerLoader$StreamMethodRequestHandler.handleRequest(EventHandlerLoader.java:373) ~[aws-lambda-java-runtime-0.2.0.jar:na]
at lambdainternal.EventHandlerLoader$2.call(EventHandlerLoader.java:897) ~[aws-lambda-java-runtime-0.2.0.jar:na]
at lambdainternal.AWSLambda.startRuntime(AWSLambda.java:228) ~[aws-lambda-java-runtime-0.2.0.jar:na]
at lambdainternal.AWSLambda.startRuntime(AWSLambda.java:162) ~[aws-lambda-java-runtime-0.2.0.jar:na]
at lambdainternal.AWSLambda.main(AWSLambda.java:157) ~[aws-lambda-java-runtime-0.2.0.jar:na]
```

<s>My source code can be found here: https://github.com/LukeShay/route-rating-rest-api/tree/switch-to-lambda</s>

Yes I know running Spring Boot on a lambda is dumb, but it is temporary. So, I don't have to pay for an EC2 instance. This is also not refined yet so I know there will be other things I should change.

EDIT: Here is the relevant code

This first one is the lambda handler. I originally had the commented out code but switched to the other because the start time was substantially faster. Both methods give the same error.

The second one is the class where the error is being encountered, which is my auth filter. I added the comment `// ERROR HERE` to the second snippet so it is easier to see the exact location of where the exception is being thrown.

```java
package com.lukeshay.restapi;

import com.amazonaws.serverless.exceptions.ContainerInitializationException;
import com.amazonaws.serverless.proxy.internal.LambdaContainerHandler;
import com.amazonaws.serverless.proxy.model.AwsProxyRequest;
import com.amazonaws.serverless.proxy.model.AwsProxyResponse;
import com.amazonaws.serverless.proxy.spring.SpringBootLambdaContainerHandler;
import com.amazonaws.serverless.proxy.spring.SpringBootProxyHandlerBuilder;
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.Context;
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.RequestStreamHandler;
import com.google.common.base.Splitter;
import com.lukeshay.restapi.config.CORSConfiguration;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.time.Instant;
import java.util.EnumSet;
import javax.servlet.DispatcherType;
import javax.servlet.FilterRegistration;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;

public class StreamLambdaHandler implements RequestStreamHandler {
  private static final Splitter SPLITTER = Splitter.on(',')
          .trimResults()
          .omitEmptyStrings();

  private static SpringBootLambdaContainerHandler<AwsProxyRequest, AwsProxyResponse> handler;

//  static {
//    try {
//      long startTime = Instant.now().toEpochMilli();
//
//      LambdaContainerHandler.getContainerConfig().setInitializationTimeout(20_000);
//
//      //      handler =
//      // SpringBootLambdaContainerHandler.getAwsProxyHandler(RestApiApplication.class);
//
//      handler =
//          new SpringBootProxyHandlerBuilder()
//              .defaultProxy()
//              .asyncInit(startTime)
//              .springBootApplication(RestApiApplication.class)
//              .profiles("lambda")
//              .buildAndInitialize();
//
//      // we use the onStartup method of the handler to register our custom filter
//      handler.onStartup(
//          servletContext -> {
//            FilterRegistration.Dynamic registration =
//                servletContext.addFilter("CORSConfiguration", CORSConfiguration.class);
//            registration.addMappingForUrlPatterns(EnumSet.of(DispatcherType.REQUEST), true, "/*");
//          });
//    } catch (ContainerInitializationException e) {
//      e.printStackTrace();
//      throw new RuntimeException("Could not initialize Spring Boot application", e);
//    }
//  }

  @Override
  public void handleRequest(InputStream inputStream, OutputStream outputStream, Context context)
      throws IOException {
    if (handler == null) {
      try {
        String listOfActiveSpringProfiles = System.getenv("SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE");
        if (listOfActiveSpringProfiles != null) {
          handler = SpringBootLambdaContainerHandler.getAwsProxyHandler(Application.class,
                  splitToArray(listOfActiveSpringProfiles));
        } else {
          long startTime = Instant.now().toEpochMilli();

          LambdaContainerHandler.getContainerConfig().setInitializationTimeout(20_000);

          handler =
                  new SpringBootProxyHandlerBuilder()
                          .defaultProxy()
                          .asyncInit(startTime)
                          .springBootApplication(RestApiApplication.class)
                          .profiles("lambda")
                          .buildAndInitialize();
        }
      } catch (ContainerInitializationException e) {
        // if we fail here. We re-throw the exception to force another cold start
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new RuntimeException("Could not initialize Spring Boot application", e);
      }
    }
    handler.proxyStream(inputStream, outputStream, context);

    outputStream.flush();
    outputStream.close();
  }

  private static String[] splitToArray(String activeProfiles) {
    return SPLITTER.splitToList(activeProfiles).toArray(new String[0]);
  }
}
```

```java
package com.lukeshay.restapi.security;

import com.lukeshay.restapi.jwt.JwtService;
import com.lukeshay.restapi.jwt.JwtServiceImpl;
import com.lukeshay.restapi.session.SessionService;
import com.lukeshay.restapi.session.SessionServiceImpl;
import com.lukeshay.restapi.user.User;
import com.lukeshay.restapi.user.UserRepository;
import io.jsonwebtoken.Claims;
import io.jsonwebtoken.ExpiredJwtException;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter;
import org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.web.context.support.WebApplicationContextUtils;

public class JwtAuthorizationFilter extends BasicAuthenticationFilter {

  private static Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JwtAuthorizationFilter.class.getName());

  private UserRepository userRepository;
  private JwtService jwtService;
  private SessionService sessionService;

  public JwtAuthorizationFilter(
      AuthenticationManager authenticationManager, UserRepository userRepository) {
    super(authenticationManager);
    this.userRepository = userRepository;
  }

  @Override
  protected void doFilterInternal(
      HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
      throws IOException, ServletException {

    if (jwtService == null) {
      ServletContext servletContext = request.getSession().getServletContext();
      WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext =
          WebApplicationContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(servletContext);  // ERROR HERE 

      jwtService = webApplicationContext.getBean(JwtServiceImpl.class);
      sessionService = webApplicationContext.getBean(SessionServiceImpl.class);
    }

    String header = request.getHeader(SecurityProperties.JWT_HEADER_STRING);

    if (header == null || !header.startsWith(SecurityProperties.TOKEN_PREFIX)) {
      chain.doFilter(request, response);
      return;
    }

    Authentication authentication = getUsernamePasswordAuthentication(request, response);
    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);

    chain.doFilter(request, response);
  }

  private Authentication getUsernamePasswordAuthentication(
      HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {

    String jwtToken =
        request
            .getHeader(SecurityProperties.JWT_HEADER_STRING)
            .replace(SecurityProperties.TOKEN_PREFIX, "");

    if (jwtToken.trim().length() == 0) {
      return null;
    }

    Claims jwtClaims;

    try {
      jwtClaims = jwtService.parseJwtToken(jwtToken);
    } catch (ExpiredJwtException expiredJwtException) {

      Claims refreshClaims;

      try {
        String refreshToken =
            request
                .getHeader(SecurityProperties.REFRESH_HEADER_STRING)
                .replace(SecurityProperties.TOKEN_PREFIX, "");

        refreshClaims = jwtService.parseJwtToken(refreshToken);
        jwtClaims = expiredJwtException.getClaims();

        if (refreshClaims.getId().equals(jwtClaims.getId())
            && refreshClaims.getSubject().equals(SecurityProperties.REFRESH_HEADER_STRING)) {

          String newJwtToken = jwtService.buildToken(jwtClaims);

          response.addHeader(
              SecurityProperties.JWT_HEADER_STRING, SecurityProperties.TOKEN_PREFIX + newJwtToken);
        }
      } catch (ExpiredJwtException | NullPointerException ignored) {
        LOG.debug("No refresh token present or refresh token is expired.");
        jwtClaims = null;
      }
    }

    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication = null;

    if (jwtClaims != null && jwtClaims.getSubject().equals(SecurityProperties.JWT_HEADER_STRING)) {
      User user = userRepository.findById(jwtClaims.getId()).orElse(null);

      if (user == null) {
        return null;
      }

      UserPrincipal principal = new UserPrincipal(user);

      LOG.debug("This user token is being created.");

      authentication =
          new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(principal, null, principal.getAuthorities());
    }

    return authentication;
  }
}
```

For more context, my source code can be found here: https://github.com/LukeShay/route-rating-rest-api/tree/switch-to-lambda

Comment: Please add your relevant code to your question. You can't expect us to hunt through your GH repo for you.

Comment: True I probably should have thought about that!

Comment: If you have already found a solution for that, do not hesitate to share it